# Protect Excel workbook from opening in outside network

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook I need to share with my client but make sure it is not opened outside of their office network.

How to protect my Excel workbook like this?

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible, whatever you do, there's a weak link: the client, if someone can read a workbook, he can copy/paste, print (even retype) it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, exactly what you request isn't (easily) possible.

Theoretically you could set the workbook to draw its data from a network resource you control, and set that resource to only allow read access from specific network addresses such as the client network. However, there are a number of hoops to jump through first, such as setting up the database server and creating the data source, testing the worksheet, and then setting up the network permissions to allow the client's addresses (and of course discovering their IP addresses). That's actually a lot more work than it even sounds.

Even all of that work wouldn't prevent the user from copying that data into another workbook (either via copy/paste or manually retyping it), or using a VPN to connect to their work-network and reading the file just fine from Tahiti or Moscow.

Sadly, the only foolproof solution is not sharing the data at all, and that doesn't let the customer see the data at all.

In IT we frequently try to reframe the problem not in terms of "how can we make this solution" but instead as "what is the problem we're trying to solve?" In this case, it sounds like the problem you're trying to solve is keeping sensitive information from falling into the wrong hands. The only solution to THAT problem that has ever been found is not to trust it to the wrong people. If you can't trust your client with this data, I'd suggest either the client isn't trustworthy, or there's something wrong with the data you're looking to share (as in, why do they need data this sensitive?).

I'd suggest re-evaluating the problem you're trying to solve. Maybe send them a screenshot of the document from a resource you control and can delete the image from after they've viewed it. They'd still be able to print or save the image, but if they're THAT persistent in getting the data, you're not going to stop them if they can see it at all, and they're not terribly trustworthy.